# What does org.freedesktop.DBus.NameLost mean?

Tags: qt, dbus, fedora-25, qtdbus

I'm getting [org.freedesktop.DBus.NameLost](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/api/org/freedesktop/DBus.NameLost.html) signal when my application tries to invoke DBus activatable session bus service.

What does this signal really means? Does this mean application cannot send signal to the DBus service anymore?

Request

```
method call time=1499719567.788200 sender=:1.439 -> destination=com.test.mytest serial=7 path=/com/test/mytest; interface=org.freedesktop.Application; member=Open
   array [
      string "mytest://192.168.121.12?message=welcome"
   ]
   array [
   ]
```

The signals emitted

```
signal time=1499719567.789882 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.439 serial=5 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameLost
   string ":1.439"
signal time=1499719567.789938 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=1045 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.439"
   string ":1.439"
   string ""
```

Comment: ...`/etc/dbus-1/system.xml` and/or `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/` probably needs a config file to allow your application through it. The second message `NameOwnerChanged` means
the unique name is no longer in use (when dbus-send exits).

Comment: @I'L'I `NameOwnerChanged` signal mean that application wont be invoked? And the unique name you mentioned is obtained with the `Open` method call or `RequestName` call?